# A subset of a topological space is closed iff it contains all its limit points - true or false?

Tags: general-topology

I read that a subset of a topological space is closed iff it contains all its limit points, in Munkres (pg. 98) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1825240/subset-of-a-topological-space-is-closed-if-and-only-if-it-contains-all-of-its-li).

On the other hand, I saw a counter example of a topological space in which all subsets contain all their limit points but not all of them are closed, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235714/if-a-set-contains-all-its-limit-points-must-it-be-closed?rq=1).

The proofs for the first saying don't seem to assume that the space is first countable, altough in the second link it says this is a necessary condition.

As to now, I am quite lost. Can anyone please help me make some sense out of this mess?

Comment: You seem to be confusing the notions of *closed set* and *sequentially closed set*. A set is closed if it contains all of its [limit points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point). A set $A$ is sequentially closed if it contains the limits of all convergent sequences of points in $A$. In a first countable space the two notions are equivalent; in other spaces they need not coincide.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You’re welcome!

Comment: The def'n of topological space is very broad. It seems to me  that many students are taught a lot about metric spaces first, and form the mistaken impression that  topological closure is always about convergent sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question has been answered in the comment by Brian M. Scott -

"You seem to be confusing the notions of closed set and sequentially closed set. A set is closed if it contains all of its [limit points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point). A set AA is sequentially closed if it contains the limits of all convergent sequences of points in AA. In a first countable space the two notions are equivalent; in other spaces they need not coincide."