# if $X$ is a subset of a topologized set $S$, then $X$ is closed if and only if $X=\bar{X}$

Tags: general-topology

So, I got the first part where I assume $X$ is closed, so $S-X$ is open. Now if there exists a limit point of $X$ let it be $p \in S$. Now if $p\in S-X$, as $S-X$ is open $X\cap (S-X)\neq\emptyset$ and $X\cap (S-X)\neq \{p\}$ but we know $X\cap S-X=\emptyset$. So, $p\notin S-X\implies p\in X$. Therefore if $\exists p\in S \ni p$ is a limit point of $X$ then $p\in X\implies X=\bar{X}$.

I cannot do the converse part. Its from topology book of John G.Hocking and Gail.S.Young

**Some background information-important information**

I have to prove this using a limited no of definitions and theorems.

the three axioms used to define a topology are given, defn of Open set is given as the sets in the topology, satisfying the three axioms , $\bar{A}$ is defined as the union of $A$ with the set containing all the limit points of $A$

and that $A$ is closed if $S-A$ is open.

And that $p\in S$ is a limit point of $X$ if all open sets containing $p$ also has another point of $X$ different from $p$

Comment: It remains to prove that given any subset $X$ of a topological space, the closure of $X$ is closed set in this topology.

Comment: yes but how? because the definition is $X$ is closed if $S-X$ is open. @Hermès

Comment: Closely related: [A subset of a topological space is closed iff it contains all its limit points - true or false?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1912653/a-subset-of-a-topological-space-is-closed-iff-it-contains-all-its-limit-points)

Comment: It is "better" to define $\bar A$ as the smallest closed set containing $A$. At least that would trivialize the problem ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen can not do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $X = \bar{X}$, and take $p\in S - X$. Then $p \in S -  \bar{X}$, so $p$ is not a limit point of $X$. Thus, there is some open set $U$ of $p$ such that $U-\{p\}$ is disjoint from $X$. So $p\in U \subset S - X$. Since $p$ was an arbitrary element of $S - X$, then $S - X$ is a union of open sets, which is open by definition of a topology. Hence, $X$ is closed.

Comment: yes but the definition of open set here is a set $O\in\{O_\alpha\}$ where $\{O_\alpha\}$ is the collection of subsets of $S$ satisfying the three axioms of a topology

Comment: @user6469329 Since I found, for each $p\in S - X$, an open set $U$ that contains $p$ and is contained in $S - X$, then I can claim that $S - X$ is a union of open sets, which is open by definition of topology.

Comment: but how do I know that $\exists U\subset S-X, p\in U \ni U$ is open. I mean how do i show that every point in $S$ there will be an open set containing that element of $S$.

Comment: Sorry @user6469329, your question is unclear. Are you asking how one knows that there is an open subset $U$ of $S$ such that $p\in U \subset S - X$? Well, if you have an open set $U$ of $p$ such that $U\cap (S - X) = \emptyset$ (which I established), then for every $y\in U$, $y\notin X $, i.e., $y\in S - X$. So $U\subset S - X$.

Comment: no no, i am asking how did you establish that $\exists U\subset S-X$ an open set containing $p$.

Comment: @user6469329 based on your text, what does it mean for $y\in \bar{X}$?

Comment: $\bar{A}=A\cup A^*$ where $A^*$ is the set containing all the limit points of $A$

Comment: @Magdiragdag but the defn of Open set is given as the sets in the topology, satisfying the three axioms

Comment: @Magdiragdag how do i know that there exists an open set $U$ around a particular $p\in S-X$ and $U\cap X=\emptyset$?

Comment: well if $p$ is a limit point then $p\in\bar{X} \notin S-X$ I get a contradiction and then get that there is no limit point in $S-X$.

There is another thing if we take $p$ as alimit point then ever open set,$O$, containing $p$ will be like $O\capX\neq\emptyset,\{p\}$, cannot tell that $\exists O\subset S$ which is open and $O\cap   X=\emptyset$

Comment: cannot find away to connect the limit point defn with $p\in S-\bar{X}$, I can take an open set $O\ni p$ but then $O \cap X\neq\emptyset,\{ p\}$. its a dead end.

Intersection of all such $O$'s and unions are useless because they areneither in $X$ nor in $S-X$ and i dont have a theorem which says that $\exists O\ni p \ni O$ is open and $O\cap X=\emptyset$

Comment: @user6469329 I edited my answer using your definitions.

Comment: @kobe how did you get this------ 

If $p$ is not a limit point, there is some open set $U$ of $p$ such that $U−{p}$ is disjoint from $X$.

it can be that $p$ is not a limit point but $U\cap X\neq\emptyset,\{p\}$

Comment: @user6469329 it's the negation of your definition for $p\in \bar{X}$. If $p\notin \bar{X}$, then there is an open set $U$ containing $p$ which contains no point $X$ different from $p$ -- in other words, for some open set $U$ containing $p$, $(U- \{p\})\cap X = \emptyset$.